# CouchDB: Struggling with concept to get data displayed in a web page

Tags: couchdb

As previously advised I have set up a database on iriscouch. Entered a couple of records.

I read in the CouchDB Guide book, I need to create a map function, in order to see my records

eg

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.date && doc.title) {
    emit(doc.date, doc.title);
  }
}
```

Now where do I put this function.  Is it a MySQL like view and saved in the database and how do I get the result to my web page ?

Do I create the view within iriscouch somehow ?

Any guidance gratefully received as it is the usual first tentative steps problem of just not getting the idea and I have yet to find a 'Hello World' example which shows all steps.

Thanks

mcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it is similar as files on a computer filesystem. Most files just store data. But some files are also programs which can run and become an application. In CouchDB, all data is stored in *documents* however some documents activate special behavior in CouchDB. These are called *design documents*.

Design documents have an id of `_design/example`, i.e. it must start with `_design/`. You can create a document with the Futon tool, just like any other document. Add a key called `views` with a value of a JSON object:

```
{ "titles_by_date":
  { "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.date && doc.title) emit(doc.date, doc.title); }"
  }
}
```

If you have other questions, there is also the [Iris Couch forum](http://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch) any discussion about CouchDB and Iris Couch.